# Are there any ports that need to be open for the Podio APIs

Tags: podio

Are there any ports or anything that need to be open to make API calls work. We are making a call to podio.authenticatwithapp from our production www server and the call is failing. We make the same call to the same app from our intranet and the call succeeds.

A podio form embedded on the page for the same app works.

Answer (score 3):

Podio API works on standard https port **443**.

I can only assume that your call is failing for some other reason(s) then not being able to connect. To give you better answer: please provide sample of your code (with all tokens, logins and passwords removed) and full stack-trace of error message.